# Service failed to start but nothing in event log

Tags: windows-event-log

I'm getting the warning that a service or driver failed to start, check the event log, but when I do, I can't find any error or warning events on any of the logs ?

Is there some way to work out what is causing the error?

Comment: What OS?... and are you sure is the system telling you this, and not some program?  Check your registry settings (HKLM>Software>Microsoft>windows>Currentbla>run) and (HKCU>...same...) or the startup folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you running? What's installed on the server? Many times, a backup program that has been uninstalled will leave a file system driver behind, or a packet capture program will leave a network layer protocol driver behind. Take a look in Device Manager at Hidden Devices and see if anything shows up with an exclamation point. If you see any then that's probably the remnant of some program that's been uninstalled but left it's drivers behind. These should be safe to disable or uninstall.

Comment: It's Windows 2003 R2, 32 bit
Thanks for the pointers, I'll check the drivers

Comment: Yeap, it was a driver ... ta

Comment: Glad to help...